# Can I travel with BDSM items?

Tags: airport-security, tips-and-tricks, lhr, security, prohibited-items

I've seen very little about this topic online and so have no idea if it's allowed for **carry on hand-baggage**.

BDSM Items:

1. Harness x2
2. Fluffy hand restraints
3. Jock straps x2
4. Feather teaser
5. Blind fold

Any comments or thoughts on whether Heathrow Airport security will allow these items in carry on hand-baggage?

Comment: Anything which can be used to restrain someone is most probably a no-no.

Comment: All those items except handcuffs should be fine in carry-on. If handcuffs are velcro-based (not metal-based), they should be fine too.

Comment: Depending on where you're going you might have trouble at your destination. The more conservative Moslem countries might frown upon them, for example.

Comment: What are the chances of being stopped by airport security? Likely they'll want to open my bag to have a look at it? How embarrassing that'll be...

Comment: I recently boarded an international flight in Australia where there was extensive signage that nothing for restraint, including handcuffs and cable ties, was allowed in carry on. Recommend checking these in to be on the safe side.

Comment: Well to update everyone, I just got through security without any issues. My bag passed straight through! Hurrah!! Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an extensive list of what can and cannot be carried in carry-on luggage at [Hand luggage restrictions at UK airports](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions).

I don't see anything in that list restricting things like handcuffs.

Comment: However there is the caveat "Airport security staff will not let anything through that they consider dangerous - even if it’s normally allowed in hand luggage.". This is a catch-all that allows staff to refuse items that were not specifically banned, as it's difficult to come up with a comprehensive list of everything that anyone might want to take on board a plane. Handcuffs if made of metal may well be such item that security staff uses thier judgement about. In this case I would think they might regard them as similar to knuckledusters which are banned as they could  be used the same way.

Comment: I got through without any issues! Bag didn't even get searched

Comment: Anecdote: 30+ years ago, this hand luggage restriction list was not readily available to me and I had the glorious idea to bring my newly purchased nunchuks on a Pan Am flight from LHR to SFO, shortly before they sold their routes to United. Police with machine guns escorted me to what resulted in a two hours interrogation. Since there was no clear policy on sports equipment back then and because I didn't show up on any international criminal database, I was allowed to export the nunchucks. However, they had to be handed over to the pilots and I got them back again when I left the plane.